# Interactive reporting tool similar to Saiku but not using Cube

Tags: java, open-source, reporting

I am looking for a interactive reporting framework / tool / engine in java similar to Saiku - http://demo.analytical-labs.com/. However, some thing that doesn't work on Cubes but rather 2-dimensional "datasets".

The reporting tool should provide basic features such as filter, sort, aggregate, export, annotate, etc.

Is there any such open source reporting tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jaspersoft has come up with Ad Hoc reporting which is exactly what I want.
It allows to create domains from RDBMS, avoiding MDX hussle and you can still view your data in multiple dimensions using Ad Hoc reporting.

Answer (score 0):

[Jaspersoft](http://www.jaspersoft.com/reporting-server) and [SpagoBI](http://www.spagoworld.org/xwiki/bin/view/SpagoBI/) provide domains where you can specify your dataset and build reports over them. Both interactive and scheduled.